# What does overclocking sensors do?

Tags: artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator

As part of the engineering station, there are various components to a ship that you can temporarily increase performance to. One of those things is the sensor array.

What does increased performance to the sensor array do, and when would be tactically beneficial to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overclocking the sensors decreases the amount of time it takes to run a scan. When to overclock depends on your game configuration.

If your game is configured such that sensors operate at unlimited range, Science should be scanning the ships idly whenever possible. You will probably only be engaging enemies you have already scanned, so overclocking is effectively never used.

However, if your game is configured such that sensors operate at a highly limited range, or if you have found yourself in combat and did not expect it, overclocking sensors can be a huge boon. You want to scan your enemies as fast as possible; this way, you know what frequency their shields are vulnerable to and waste less time in movement.

Generally, there's no reason to overclock, but do it when you need the information from Science *immediately*.